# Как перенести поля в woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как перенести "населенный пункт" и "облать регион" в правую сторону?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблон полей доставки и комментария

wp-content/themes/ваша_тема/woocommerce/checkout/form-shipping.php

Можно его видоизменить

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<div class="woocommerce-shipping-fields">
    <?php if ( true === WC()->cart->needs_shipping_address() ) : ?>

        <h3 id="ship-to-different-address">
            <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
                <input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" <?php checked( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'shipping' === get_option( 'woocommerce_ship_to_destination' ) ? 1 : 0 ), 1 ); ?> type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address" value="1" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Ship to a different address?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
            </label>
        </h3>

        <div class="shipping_address">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_shipping_form', $checkout ); ?>

            <div class="woocommerce-shipping-fields__field-wrapper">
                <?php
                $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'shipping' );

                foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
                    
                    if ($key == 'shipping_city' || $key == 'shipping_state') continue;
                    
                    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_shipping_form', $checkout ); ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="woocommerce-additional-fields">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', $checkout ); ?>
    
    <?php foreach (['shipping_city', 'shipping_state'] as $key) : ?>
    
        <?php if (isset($fields[$key])) : ?>
        
            <?php $field = $fields[$key]; ?>
            
            <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
        
        <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_order_comments', 'yes' ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->needs_shipping() || wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() ) : ?>

            <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Additional information', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-additional-fields__field-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'order' ) as $key => $field ) : ?>
                <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', $checkout ); ?>
</div>
```